# Prove that $f_n \to 0$ in measure on $[0,1]$ $\iff$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{e}^{-|f_n(x)|^2} =1$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Prove that $f_n \to 0$ in measure on $[0,1]$ $\iff$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{e}^{-|f_n(x)|^2} =1$

My proof:

Forward: Since $\mathbb{e}^{-x^2}$ is continuous we know that $\mathbb{e}^{-|f_n(x)|^2}\to 1$ in measure. Thus by DCT $\mathbb{e}^{-|f_n(x)|^2}\leq1$ we get the limit.

Backwards: Assume towards contradiction that $f_n \not \to 0$, then $\mu(x| |f_{n_k}|>\delta)>\epsilon$ for some $\delta,\epsilon$. Name these sets $A_k$ Thus $\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{e}^{-|f_{n_k}(x)|^2}=\int_{A_k}\mathbb{e}^{-|f_{n_k}(x)|^2}+\int_{A_k^c}\mathbb{e}^{-|f_{n_k}(x)|^2}\leq\epsilon\mathbb{e}^{-\delta^2}+1-\epsilon<1$ contradiction

IS my proof correct? Is there a more direct way?

Comment: I don't think you negated the definition of $f_n \to 0$ in measure correctly in your "backwards" part. Check your quantifiers carefully

Comment: @MoonBears-C- $\forall \delta \forall \epsilon \exists N \forall n\geq N$ no?

Comment: I mess this up all the time, but from what I can tell it's "For every epsilon there exists a delta" negates to "For every delta there exists an epsilon" so it goes "For all delta, there exists an epsilon such that..."

Comment: @MoonBears-C- I am pretty sure negating a quantifier only switches exists with for all and viec versa + negates whatever is inside. The variables do not get swapped.

Comment: You wrote "for some delta, for some epsilon" above without changing the quantifier

Comment: @MoonBears-C- I am not really sure where my mistake is. Anyway, the order in my proof does not matter. I just need some delta and epsilon no matter how they are dependent.

Comment: @MoonBears-C- : See my answer. You are right that "for all" negates as "there exists", but in the definition, there are two "for alls."

Comment: How do you apply the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @clark DCT is valid even if $f_n \to f$ in measure.

Comment: To apply DCT you also need $f_n\to f$ pointwise. You can use DCT to show that when $f_n\to f$ in measure and $f_n$ are continuous and bounded then the convergence is in $L^1$

Comment: @clark It is a standard trick of passing into subsequence. in measure implies convergence a.e of a subsequence. Show every subsequence has a convergent subsequence in $L^1$

Comment: Right, that's correct. So, in writing the solution I would quote that result depending on the level of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of convergence in measure: For all $\delta>0$, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu \{x:\, |f_n(x)|>\delta\}=0.
$$
In other words, for all $\epsilon>0$, $\delta>0$, there exists $N=N(\epsilon,\delta)$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$
\mu \{x:\, |f_n(x)|>\delta\}<\epsilon.
$$
The negation is there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ and $\delta_0$ such that for all $k$, there exists $n_k\geq k$ such that 
$$
\mu \{x:\, |f_{n_k}(x)|>\delta_0\}\geq \epsilon_0.
$$
Hence, I believe your backward direction is correct with some recommendations. You should make a remark that since the limit exists, so does
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1 e^{-|f_{n_k}(x)|^2}\,dx\leq \epsilon e^{-\delta^2}+1-\epsilon<1.
$$
As you have it right now, it looks like you are just showing that some terms are bounded by something less than 1. I know what you mean, but I would be more explicit with the limits.

Comment: Details: Since every sub sequence has to converge to 1 thus this applied to $f_{n_k}$. I have show that this subsequence (if) converges to something less than 1. Which leads to contradiction. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, I like that.